# how can i filter a dataframe by some criteria and then save .csv?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, finance

Hi guys i started at jupyter notebook few days ago.

I need help, i have a dataframe by panda. something like this

```
Date    Stock   Company   Volume

01/02    APPL3   Apple     1.000.000

01/02    YUSS    Yusduqs     200.000

01/02    APPL4    Apple      200.000

01/02    DISN    Disney      1.500.000

02/02    APPL3    Apple       100.000

02/02    YUSS    Yusduqs     1.250.000

02/02    DISN     Disney     2.000.000

02/02    APPL4    Apple     1.250.000

 ...            ...           ....
```

I need to select the stock that was traded in more than 80% of the days with volume greater than $ 500.000,00 per day.

And i need to select **only one stock per firm, the criterio is which has more volume in all days combined. Like for 'Apple' in [Company] i have two diferents [Stock] Appl3 and Appl4, in this specific case i only need APPL4.

(Because Volume of the days combined in Appl4 > Volume of the days combined in Appl3)

I started like this:

`unique_dates=len(df['Date'].value_counts()) 
share_freq=df[df['Volume']>=500000]]['Stock'].value_counts() stocks=share_freq/unique_dates for stock,value in stocks.items(): 
      if(value>0.8): 
          print(stock)`

So after that i can see which one has>0.8 but i still need to select only one stock per firm. I dont know how to respect all the criterios and by the end filter all the dataframe by the criterios and save in .csv

Comment: Can you build a title that's more specific to exactly what you got stuck on? A good title doesn't just give people a good idea on whether they know the answer to your question -- it also helps *other people with the same problem* tell if your question's answers will help them. "I don't know where to start" doesn't really help anyone know if they have the same problem, which prevents this from being a useful knowledgebase entry in the context of Stack Overflow's [effort to build a long-tail FAQ](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/).

Comment: Sure, thanks for the tip @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `nunique`

```
n=df.loc[df['Volume']>=500000,'Date'].groupby(df['Stock']).nunique()
uniquedate=df.Date.nunique()
n=n[n/uniquedate >0.8]
print(n.index)
```

Update

```
df.loc[df.Stock.isin(n.index)].to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: Yeah that works i can see which companies has >0.8. But now how can i drop all the stocks which doesn't have >0.8 and then save in .excel?

Comment: @GlauberNaue check the update ,also if this help, would like consider accept ?